# Hardware timestamping PCAP

Tags: c++, networking, timestamp, kernel, pcap

I'm building a c++ latency measurement library, with the intention on getting as close to a network-only latency measurement.  Hardware timestamping seems to be the way to go.

I'm using a sniffer to detect packets sent over TCP.  My question is, to get the soonest timestamp possible, which should I be using - kernel's `SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_HARDWARE` or libpcap's `PCAP_TSTAMP_ADAPTER`?

What is the difference?  My guess is they both return the same values, since they are seeking the timestamp at the NIC, logically meaning it doesn't matter which is used.  Is this the case?

Comment: "_I'm building a c++ latency measurement library_" To what purpose? Latency changes from one measurement to another. There really is no such thing as a single latency, except on a completely unloaded link.

Comment: Network latency between two hosts on a local network.  As close as possible to the time difference between a packet leaving host A's NIC and arriving at host B's NIC.  Both timestamps will be sent to a supervisor and difference will be calculated.  Assume both NIC's are identical.

Comment: But why? The latency will vary as the network load increases or decreases. It is really meaningless. Even network switches have some buffering, as small as it is, and the latency will constantly vary.

Comment: I'm trying to simplify things as I thought that would help.  It has no impact on my question whether we are measuring on a global scale or not.  With all due respect, either answer the question or don't.  My motives aren't where my issue is.

Comment: OK. I'm simply pointing out that the latency measurement is only good for the time that you measured it, and will not be good for any time period before or after you measure it. I just don't see the point in a latency library. I do, however see a point in a jitter tool because jitter can affect real-time protocols, e.g. VoIP.